# ¿Cómo configurar correctamente proyecto de react con typescript para ser usado como un modulo?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

¡Hola!

Tengo un módulo y una app hechos en react con typescript, quiero importar un componente del módulo en la app, pero al parecer la app no reconoce que el módulo esta hecho en typescript, me aparece el siguiente error:

```javascript
ERROR in ./src/App.tsx 12:35-41
export 'default' (imported as 'Header') was not found in 'test-module' (possible exports: Header)

ERROR in ./node_modules/test-module/src/components/Header.tsx 3:0
Module parse failed: The keyword 'interface' is reserved (3:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| import React, { FC, ReactElement } from 'react';
| 
> interface HeaderProps {
|   name: string;
|   children?: ReactElement;

ERROR in src/App.tsx:3:8
TS2613: Module '"/react/test-app/node_modules/test-module/index"' has no default export. Did you mean to use 'import { Header } from "/react/test-app/node_modules/test-module/index"' instead?
    1 | import React from 'react';
    2 | import './App.css';
  > 3 | import Header from 'test-module';
      |        ^^^^^^
    4 | //import Header from './components/Header';
    5 |
    6 | function App() {
```

Dentro del módulo agregue un index.ts en la raíz del proyecto con la siguiente configuración:

```javascript
export { default as Header } from './src/components/Header';
```

el package.json del módulo tiene agregado:

```json
"main": "index.ts",
```

No entiendo porque dice que no tiene un default export cuando aparentemente le agregué uno.

Si copio directamente el componente del módulo dentro de la app este funciona correctamente, como pueden ver en el siguiente video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eu4_gdXTDb8

¿Sabrán que me faltará por configurar para que la app importe correctamente el módulo?

Dejo el código del módulo https://github.com/sgb004/react-typescript-module-test por si quieren revisar con más detalle la configuración del package.json, también dejo el de app https://github.com/sgb004/react-typescript-app-test por si quieren recrear el error.

De antemano, muchas gracias por su ayuda :D